# Am having trouble defining Entry model , i keep getting TypeError with the class Meta

Tags: django-models

I keep running into `TypeError: 'Class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): verbos_name_plural.`

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
#Class for topic.
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the use is learning about"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Retun a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text


class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about a topic"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        verbos_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

This code is actually giving me a hard time in defining Entry model and i have tried taking the class Meta out of the code since it was the `Error` i had first, but  i still run into an `Error` with the class Topic after i had deleted the class Meta . i would be glad if anyone can help me.

Comment: It is `verbose_name_plural`, *not* `verbos_name_plural`. (with an `e` at the end of `verbose`)

Comment: Thank you so much @WillemVanOnsem ,  i added the (e) and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'
```

instead of

```
class Meta:
        verbos_name_plural = 'entries'
```